# What are the difference between useInfiniteQuery vs QueryClientProvider usage in React Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

So I've encountered a confusion on the preferable usage of `QueryClientProvider` and `useInfiniteQuery`. I've been using the `useInfiniteQuery` function as a global state on some of the rendered components at the same time. Then I faced a problem where there is a component which has not been rendered yet to fetch the same data using the same `useInfiniteQuery`. When the component is triggered to render, it will cause the `useInfiniteQuery` to fetch again. I've solved this problem by giving an `queryOptions` of `enabled` set to `false`, so the `useInfiniteQuery` will not fetch automatically.

[Sandbox Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-usage-n4hzr4?file=/src/index.js) (Note: You might want to set the Network into slow 3G, and try to use the `enabled: false` query option).

Is this the preferred way to use React Query or is it better if I just use `QueryClientProvider`? Are there any pros and cons regarding both of the options?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking, comparing `QueryClientProvider` with `useInfiniteQuery` is like comparing a context provider with `useState` hook. `QueryClientProvider` provides the query client context to your components while `useInfiniteQuery` is a hook for fetching data with infinite scrolling. As for refetching when a component with same query mounts, see `staleTime`, `cacheTime`, `refetchOnMount` and other options in the docs.

Comment: @JakubKotrs You can actually use the hook `useInfiniteQuery` or `useQuery` to fetch the same data for different components as long as it is rendered during the `staleTime` duration or when the data is fresh. More here: [https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-as-a-state-manager](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-as-a-state-manager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way is to always use the hooks in components, `useQuery` or `useInfiniteQuery`. Per default, stale queries will be refetched in the background when a component mounts that uses a query - you'll be instantly given the data though if it exists.

If you don't want background refetches, the best way is to set a `staleTime` for your query. You can also turn off `refetchOnMount`, but setting a `staleTime` is preferred because it will tackle all sorts of background refetches (e.g. onWindowFocus). More here: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-as-a-state-manager